# How to check what database pool is used with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot 1.3.1 with MySQL. I am getting this in my logs:

```
The last packet successfully received from the server was 97,025,381 milliseconds ago.  
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 97,025,381 milliseconds ago. 
is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. 
You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, 
increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, 
or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
```

Full stack:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 97,025,381 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 97,025,381 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar!/:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:981) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar!/:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3652) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar!/:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2460) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar!/:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar!/:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2547) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar!/:5.1.38]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:4874) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar!/:5.1.38]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor70.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:126) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:81) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.30.jar!/:na]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.setAutoCommit(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1471) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:61) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar!/:4.3.11.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:170) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:427) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        ... 80 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140) ~[na:1.8.0_66]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3634) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar!/:5.1.38]
```

According to [spring boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html), the tomcat-pool should normally be used automatically since I depend on the JPA starter:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Is there a way to check this?

The `/beans` endpoint returns a bean like this:

```
{
"bean": "dataSource",
"scope": "singleton",
"type": "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource",
"resource": "class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]",
"dependencies": []
}
```

So I think it is using the tomcat pool.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31372150/spring-boot-web-app-loses-ability-to-connect-to-mysql-rds-after-a-while) talks about `spring.datasource.test-while-idle` and `spring.datasource.validation-interval`. Do you need to set them to avoid the problem?

Comment: I am not sure I get the relationship between the title of your issue and the actual problem. So, yes it's using the Tomcat connection pool as you found out.

Comment: Ok, sorry about the bad title. But why do I get the exception? Do I need to use those last 2 properties to avoid it? Any link to docs that explain those?

Comment: It's written there, in the stack trace you posted: `at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spring-boot-starter-jdbc (referenced by the jpa-data as well) is depending on Tomcat pooling, so **by default you are using Tomcat pooling**. You can easily verify that by checking your maven dependency list. *(the stacktrace you posted also confirms that)*.

Which means that you should be using the [tomcat-pooling parameters](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Common_Attributes):

- testWhileIdle
- validationInterval
- validationQuery

Comment: Thanks for this. Just now found out this nice answer that explains the properties in more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30451470/connection-to-db-dies-after-424-in-spring-boot-jpa-hibernate